# Selenium no recoge el proxy

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

El código abre el navegador e intenta conectar a el proxy para hacer la conexión final, el error es invalid argument pero esto ocurre una vez abierto el navegador e intenta hacer la conexión, creo que es porque en

```
options.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' % proxy1)
```

el proxy debe ser añadido de forma manual y entre comillas simples, no obstante tengo una lista y no sé como hacer para indicar correctamente el proxy. Si alguien sabe si ese es el error y me ayuda, muchas gracias, si ese no es el error, por favor indiquen cuál es, gracias.

```
try:

    proxy1 = proxy.readline().rstrip()
    options.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' % proxy1)
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
    consulta = driver.get('www.fotocasa.es/es/')
    aceptarcookies = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/div/footer/div/button[2]')
except Exception as ex:
    print(proxy1)
    driver.quit()
    print(ex)
    main()
```

Comment: ¿Cual proxy estás ocupando?

Comment: Es una lista con más de 1000 proxys pero, no sé si el problema es del proxy, creo que si falla la conexión no salta al siguiente pero no me salta la alerta, se queda esperando a imprimir algo el programa y termina saliendo.

Comment: Proporciona una lista con 5 proxies de tu elección.

Comment: Candida Moe perdona tio que es que me he confundido quería responder con eso a la otra nueva pregunta, pensé que escribió usd ahí.